# VBA Do While Loop - Wont run

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report that currently works to pull the component_cd for a single constituent_cd. I have been asked to run the report for multiple constiuent_cds. Therefore I need to convert this formula to VBA. I am stuck at my `Do While Loop`. -- FIXED ONE PROBLEM AND CREATED A NEW ONE. NOW MY FIST FOR LOOP WONT PROCESS PAST THE FIRST ROTATION.

I have included an image of the working data output and working formula, along with my VBA Code (UPDATED). I know I have messed up the `Do While loop` as everything else has been tested and works. Can anyone help me untangle this loop?

[Constituent Table][1]

Working formula:

```
=IF((VALUE(LEFT(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX(ComponentData!D:D,MATCH('START-DATA_State'!$C$2,ComponentData!D:D,0),1)),TRUE),H2+1,0),LEN($E$2)))=$C$2),OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL'("address",INDEX(ComponentData!D:D,MATCH('START-DATA_State'!'$C$2,ComponentData!D:D,0),1)),TRUE),H2+1,0),"")

len_constituent_cd_for_finding_component_cd = LEN(IF(OR('START-DATA_State'!$C$2<5,'START-DATA_State'!$C$2=6),TEXT('START-DATA_State'!$C$2,"00"),'START-DATA_State'!$C$2))

=IF((
VALUE(
LEFT(
OFFSET(
INDIRECT(
CELL("address",
INDEX(ComponentData!constituent_state,MATCH('START-DATA_State'!State_Abbreviation,ComponentData!constituent_state,EXACT),1)),TRUE),row_offset_count+1,0),

len_constituent_cd_for_finding_component_cd)) = constituent_cd),

TRUE

OFFSET(
INDIRECT(
CELL("address",
INDEX(ComponentData!constituent_state,
MATCH('START-DATA_State!constituent_cd,ComponentData!constituent_state,EXACT),1)),TRUE),row_offset_count+1,0),

FALSE

'"")
```

VBA Code:

```
Dim myLookupValue As String
Dim myFirstColumn As Long
Dim myLastColumn As Long
Dim myColumnIndex As Long
Dim myFirstRow As Long
Dim myLastRow As Long
Dim myVLookupResult As String
Dim intConstituentLength As Integer
Dim strConstituentLength As String
Dim myColumn As Long
Dim myTableArray As Range
Dim myWorkRange As Range
Dim lgth_Consti
Dim i, r, n As Integer

    myColumn = 5
myLastRow = Worksheets("START-DATA_State").Range("G2").Value '=count_NonBlankCellsColumn
myColumnIndex = 1
n = 0
r = 0


count_NonBlankCellsColumn

For i = 0 To myLastRow

    myConstituentCd = Worksheets("START-DATA_State").Cells(j + 2, 5).Value
    intConstituentCd = Worksheets("START-DATA_State").Cells(r + 2, 5).Value
    strConstituentCd = CStr(Right("0" & intConstituentCd, 2))
    intConstituentLength = Len(intConstituentCd)
    strConstituentLength = Len(strConstituentCd)


    If (myConstituentCd < 5) Or (myConstituentCd = 6) Then


        For n = 0 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), strConstituentCd = Left(WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), WorksheetFunction.Match(strConstituentCd, Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), 0)), strConstituentLength))
            Do While strConstituentCd = Left(WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), WorksheetFunction.Match(strConstituentCd, Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), 0)).Offset(rowOffset:=r + 1, columnOffset:=0), strConstituentLength)

                If strConstituentLength < Len(WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), WorksheetFunction.Match(strConstituentCd, Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), 0)).Offset(rowOffset:=n + 1, columnOffset:=0)) Then
                    Worksheets("START-DATA_State").Cells(r + 2, 6).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), WorksheetFunction.Match(strConstituentCd, Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), 0)).Offset(rowOffset:=r + 1, columnOffset:=0)
                End If
                r = r + 1

            Loop
        Next n


    Else

        For n = 0 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), intConstituentCd = CLng(Left(CStr(WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), WorksheetFunction.Match(strConstituentCd, Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), 0))), intConstituentLength)))
            Do While intConstituentCd = Left(WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), WorksheetFunction.Match(strConstituentCd, Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), 0)).Offset(rowOffset:=r + 1, columnOffset:=0), intConstituentCd)

                If strConstituentLength < Len(WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), WorksheetFunction.Match(strConstituentCd, Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), 0)).Offset(rowOffset:=n + 1, columnOffset:=0)) Then
                    Worksheets("START-DATA_State").Cells(r + 2, 6).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), WorksheetFunction.Match(strConstituentCd, Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643"), 0)).Offset(rowOffset:=r + 1, columnOffset:=0)
                End If
                r = r + 1

            Loop
        Next n


    End If
    j = j + 1
Next i
```

I am UNABLE TO GET THE i TO LOOP PAST THE FIRST ROTATION.

Comment: What's the condition of your loop? Do while `LEFT()`...? This looks a little convoluted, it may help to revisit that part and see if you can set up variables or something so it's more clear.

Comment: `strConstituentLength` is declared as a String but you are using it to store a length. Probably not your main problem but you should use correctly-typed variables.

Comment: This is a convoluted problem @BruceWayne. It was a pain to get one Constituent to work, much less multiple. The Constituent code is the LEFT first characters of the Component code (see picture). So basically for every  selected Constituent codes I need to pull the Component code that starts with the selected Constituent codes. To make matters worse some Component codes or two characters in length (01 - must be string if less than 10) and some are one character in length (5 - must be number (long)). So making variables has been difficult for me.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville - I need to store the length as a string and number hence the two near duplicate variable names. See my explanation to . If you know of another way to deal with the data being pulled being two different data types, please let me know. I would greatly appreciate the fix. It is driving me crazy.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - Thanks for the tips! I am so new to coding and I don't exactly work with a team of programmers so I kinda piece mill code bits I find online or in books that work. I don't always know best practices.

Comment: `Len()` is always going to return an integer and you should convert `intConstituentLength` to a string padded with 0 like this: `strConstituentLength = Right("0" & intConstituentLength, 2)`. Your current code will not have the leading 0 you expect.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville Sweet fix to my data type problem. Though I still need to figure out how to get the vLookup to work in the Do While Loop.

Comment: I think I need to break down the original if statement more as I think I think I need to simplify my code. The first part of the original IF excel formula is:

=IF((
VALUE(
LEFT(
OFFSET(
INDIRECT(
CELL("address",
INDEX(ComponentData!constituent_state,MATCH('START-DATA_State'!State_Abbreviation,ComponentData!constituent_state,EXACT),1)),TRUE),row_offset_count+1,0),

So I need the following:
1) Loop to go through the number of selected Constituent Cd
2) Loop to go through the Component Cd that the LEFT characters match the Constituent Cd, skipping the first record it find.

Comment: Fix one thing and broke another. My loop wont pull the data for anything but the first Constituent Code. I can't figure out which loop is out of order:

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for anyone who needs help with loops here is the solution that works:

Sub findComponent_Cd()

```
Dim myLookupValue As String
Dim myFirstColumn As Long
Dim myLastColumn As Long
Dim myColumnIndex As Long
Dim myFirstRow As Long
Dim myLastRow As Long
Dim myVLookupResult As String
Dim intConstituentLength As Long
Dim strConstituentLength As String
Dim intComponentCdLft As Long
Dim strComponentCdLft As String
Dim intConstituentCd As Long
Dim strConstituentCd As String
Dim myConstituentCd As Long
Dim myColumn As Long
Dim myCount As Long
Dim myTableArray As Range
Dim myWorkRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Dim i, r, n, j As Long

count_NonBlankCellsColumn

myColumn = 5
myLastRow = Worksheets("START-DATA_State").Range("G2").Value '=count_NonBlankCellsColumn
myColumnIndex = 1
n = 0
r = 0




For i = 0 To myLastRow

    intConstituentCd = Worksheets("START-DATA_State").Cells(j + 2, 5).Value
    strConstituentCd = CStr(Right("0" & intConstituentCd, 2))
    intConstituentLength = Len(intConstituentCd)
    strConstituentLength = Len(strConstituentCd)

 If (intConstituentCd = 5) Or _
    (intConstituentCd = 7) Or _
    (intConstituentCd = 8) Or _
    (intConstituentCd = 30) Or _
    (intConstituentCd = 33) Or _
    (intConstituentCd = 39) Or _
    (intConstituentCd = 47) Or _
    (intConstituentCd = 51) Or _
    (intConstituentCd = 99) Then

    strConstituentCd = intConstituentCd
    intConstituentLength = Len(intConstituentCd)
    strConstituentLength = intConstituentLength - 3

        For Each myCell In Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643")

            If Len(Left(myCell.Value, strConstituentLength)) = strConstituentLength Then

                If strConstituentCd = Left(myCell.Value, strConstituentLength) Then

                    If Len(myCell.Value) > strConstituentLength Then

                        If IsNumeric(myCell.Value) Then 'GoTo NextIteration

                            Worksheets("START-DATA_State").Cells(r + 2, 6).Value = myCell.Value

                            r = r + 1

                        End If

                    End If

                End If

            End If

        Next myCell

    End If

    If (intConstituentCd < 5) Or (intConstituentCd = 6) Then

        If (intConstituentCd <> 5) Or _
           (intConstituentCd <> 7) Or _
           (intConstituentCd <> 8) Or _
           (intConstituentCd <> 30) Or _
           (intConstituentCd <> 33) Or _
           (intConstituentCd <> 39) Or _
           (intConstituentCd <> 47) Or _
           (intConstituentCd <> 51) Or _
           (intConstituentCd <> 99) Then

            For Each myCell In Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643")

                If Len(Left(myCell.Value, strConstituentLength)) = strConstituentLength Then

                    If strConstituentCd = Left(myCell.Value, strConstituentLength) Then

                        Worksheets("START-DATA_State").Cells(r + 2, 6).Value = myCell.Value

                        r = r + 1

                    End If

                End If

            Next myCell

        End If

    Else

    If (intConstituentCd > 8) Then

        If (intConstituentCd <> 5) Or _
           (intConstituentCd <> 7) Or _
           (intConstituentCd <> 8) Or _
           (intConstituentCd <> 30) Or _
           (intConstituentCd <> 33) Or _
           (intConstituentCd <> 47) Or _
           (intConstituentCd <> 51) Or _
           (intConstituentCd <> 99) Then

            strConstituentCd = intConstituentCd
            strConstituentLength = Len(strConstituentCd)

            For Each myCell In Worksheets("ComponentData").Range("G2:G643")

              If Len(Left(myCell.Value, strConstituentLength)) = strConstituentLength Then

                  If strConstituentCd = Left(myCell.Value, strConstituentLength) Then

                      Worksheets("START-DATA_State").Cells(r + 2, 6).Value = myCell.Value

                      r = r + 1

                  End If

              End If

            Next myCell

        End If

    End If

 End If
 j = j + 1

Next i
```

End Sub